# Linux, fdisk: change order of partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk

I have a harddrive with 24 logical partitions on it. Half of them are Linux and half are windows. Current ordering is: 3 Linux partitions; 12 windows partitions; 9 Linux partitions. In this setup, Windows can access any of partition (no limits on partition number), but Linux can't access sda16, sda17 ...

Can I change numbering of partitions without moving them on disk? I want to put all Linux partitions to be <16; and windows partitions to be > 16, so linux will be able to access all linux partitions.

I have fdisk/sfdisk and it sees all partitions.

Comment: I probably don't want to know, but *why* do you have so many partitions?

Comment: Files are laid more compact, when kept on different partitions (one  partition to develop c++ programs, other with ISOs of Linux, other with Win. software, one with photoes, one for photo editing with heavy disk I/O,...). Also, I have many OSes installed, each with several versions. Also, some partitions were byte-by-byte copied from failed HDDs - and there are some partitions from such actions. I'm not counting partitions from virtual environments.

Comment: But after all, it is just a sad fact, that I have too much partitions to access them from Linux. And I can easily solve this with just relinking a partition tables, so Linux partitions will have smaller numbers.

Comment: apart from the fact that your disc setup is pretty crazy and changing anything will be hell because of the primary/logical setup (chained extended partition tables). im pretty sure you cant change the number the OS assigns. even if the part table contains start, size and end sector, the resulting setup would be to weird an unconventional for any OS to understand :)

Comment: I want reorder  chain (linked list) of extended tables (reorder extended partitions), even without touching primary partitions. This is possible, because linux fdisk has an option to "Sort" partition order if it differs from real disk layout (e.g.  {ext1 ext3 ext2} will be sorted to {ext1 ext2 ext3} ). In this case I want a reverse operation, 
unsort".

Comment: I know (I sure) that any OS I use will understand new world order or partitions. E.g. linux uses UUID/LABEL searchng for partition, not by number; windows will give letters to fats/ntfss based on their order (ignoring any unknown partition) or even based on fixed letter assignments.

Comment: I just feel that I have to point out that having this many partitions will cause a *horrible* performance hit.

Comment: David Schwartz, you mean that having lot partitions is slower than mixing millions of files on single multiterabyte partition? Why you do think so? I think, that if related files are kept closer, there will be less disk seeks (and seeks will be between closer cylinders) when I work with that class of files and less fragmentation (not only file fragmentation, but also directory fragmentation).

Comment: `Files are laid more compact, when kept on different partitions...` that only applies if you have a crappy filesystem \*coughfat32ntfscough\* and does not apply to any of the modern filesystems.

Comment: Bobby, the fat32 is not the only way of decompacting files. Even if I have very good single fs on 2 TB HDD, files from single c++ project (very huge, like gcc/ROOT/etc) will be spreaded over all disk. This is not about single file fragmentation, it is about fragmentation of directory and its subdirectory. I assume that when I keep similar files on separate fs, them are laid closer (spreaded over less space; without mixing with temporary many-gb files from image editing) and HDD seeks will be shorter (faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange the partition table using `sfdisk`, which is very risky (vulnerable to human error) but probably the only way. I described how to do that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18752/change-the-number-of-the-partition-of-sda1-to-sda2/18759#18759) - you'll need to adapt the procedure to your specific scenario.

Comment: I think, sfdisk is capable of this action (so does openbsd's fdisk but at lower layer). But my problem was solved via `mount -o offset=##### /dev/sda sda20`)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, but if you are feeling adventurous, you may try this:

Prepare to compile your own kernel, then go to the sources, edit `drivers/scsi/sd.c` and look for the line

```
#define SD_MINORS 16
```

And increase this number, then recompile the kernel.

Then depending on your distribution, you may need to create device files by hand with mknod. Or your device names may become completely messed up.

Good luck

Comment: b0fh, this is wrong question to post this answer. Here I try to get information how to change order of partitions to keep current kernel. And here http://superuser.com/questions/357101/linux-kernel-cant-access-sda16-sda17 I ask about other way of fixing problem: changing the kernel. As I know, in newer kernels sda16 may become sdb1, but I'm not sure and I don't know, which version of kernel I need.